# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StaffID', table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using query builder to insert into the LeaveApplication table. Supposedly when i click the apply leave, they should have a message "Application success". Instead, I am getting this error: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'StaffID', table; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated". It might something to do with my query builder to fix the error. But I don't how to fix it.  I'll attach a couple of images below of my code, and the error.

My Output:

[click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BwOB.jpg)

**LeaveApplication** DB Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LeaveApplications] (
    [Id]                 INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StaffId]            INT          NOT NULL,
    [LeaveTypeId]        INT          NOT NULL,
    [StartDate]          VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [StartLeavePeriodId] INT          NOT NULL,
    [EndDate]            VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL,
    [EndLeavePeriodId]   INT          NOT NULL,
    [NumDays]            FLOAT (53)   NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_LeaveApplications_ToStaff] FOREIGN KEY ([StaffId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Staff] ([StaffId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_LeaveApplications_ToLeaveType] FOREIGN KEY ([LeaveTypeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LeaveType] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_LeaveApplications_ToStartLeavePeriod] FOREIGN KEY ([StartLeavePeriodId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LeavePeriod] ([LeavePeriodId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_LeaveApplications_ToEndLeavePeriod] FOREIGN KEY ([EndLeavePeriodId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[LeavePeriod] ([LeavePeriodId])
);
```

**ApplyLeave.aspx** coding:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ApplyLeave.aspx.cs" Inherits="BookReservation.ApplyLeave" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <h3>Leave Application</h3>
    <asp:Label ID="lblLeaveType" runat="server" CssClass="labelClass" Text="Leave Type:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLeaveType" runat="server" Width="200px" DataSourceID="SqlDSLeaveType" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" CssClass="labelClass" Text="Start Date:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbStartDate" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalExtStartDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbStartDate" />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblStartLeavePeriod" runat="server" CssClass="labelClass" Text="Start Leave Period:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStartLeavePeriod" runat="server" Width="110px" DataSourceID="SqlDSStartLeavePeriod" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="LeavePeriodId">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="labelClass" Text="End Date:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbEndDate" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalExtEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="tbEndDate" />
    <asp:CompareValidator ID="cvEndDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Select a date" ControlToCompare="tbStartDate" ControlToValidate="tbEndDate" ForeColor="Red"></asp:CompareValidator>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblEndLeavePeriod" runat="server" CssClass="labelClass" Text="End Leave Period:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEndLeavePeriod" runat="server" Width="110px" DataSourceID="SqlDSEndLeavePeriod" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="LeavePeriodId">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnApply" runat="server" Text="Apply Leave" OnClick="btnApply_Click" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSLeaveType" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LeaveManagementCS %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [LeaveType]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSStartLeavePeriod" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LeaveManagementCS %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [LeavePeriod]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSEndLeavePeriod" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LeaveManagementCS %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [LeavePeriod]"></asp:SqlDataSource> <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSApplyLeave" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LeaveManagementCS %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [LeaveApplications] WHERE [Id] = @Id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [LeaveApplications] ([StaffId], [LeaveTypeId], [StartDate], [StartLeavePeriodId], [EndDate], [EndLeavePeriodId], [NumDays]) VALUES (@StaffId, @LeaveTypeId, @StartDate, @StartLeavePeriodId, @EndDate, @EndLeavePeriodId, @NumDays)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [LeaveApplications]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [LeaveApplications] SET [StaffId] = @StaffId, [LeaveTypeId] = @LeaveTypeId, [StartDate] = @StartDate, [StartLeavePeriodId] = @StartLeavePeriodId, [EndDate] = @EndDate, [EndLeavePeriodId] = @EndLeavePeriodId, [NumDays] = @NumDays WHERE [Id] = @Id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="StaffId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlLeaveType" Name="LeaveTypeId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbStartDate" Name="StartDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlStartLeavePeriod" Name="StartLeavePeriodId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="tbEndDate" Name="EndDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlEndLeavePeriod" Name="EndLeavePeriodId" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NumDays" Type="Double" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="StaffId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="LeaveTypeId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="StartLeavePeriodId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="EndLeavePeriodId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="NumDays" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource><br />

</asp:Content>
```

**ApplyLeave.aspx.cs** coding:

```
public partial class ApplyLeave : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalExtStartDate.StartDate = DateTime.Today;
        }

        protected void btnApply_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlDSApplyLeave.Insert();
                lblOutput.Text = "Application success";
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = ex.Message;
            }

        }
    }
```

InsertQuery:

[click image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHLXI.jpg)

Comment: Seems clear that you aren't providing a value for StaffId. Solution is to either provide a value for StaffId or remove the "not null" when creating the column.

Comment: You need to provide the value for StaffId It is for maintain the referential integrity between the table. If you allow null value of StaffId there is no point in having this column in  this table because there is no guarantee that you always get the staffID from here.

Comment: you have referenced the staffid in LeavApplications so you should only insert the data to staffid column what ever has in staff table so you can't insert the null value just check value of the staff id what is your passing

Answer (score 0):

Remove NOT NULL from StaffID, so change this:

```
[StaffId]            INT          NOT NULL,
```

to this:

```
[StaffId]            INT          ,
```

and your Foreign Key must allow also NULL here:

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_LeaveApplications_ToStaff] FOREIGN KEY ([StaffId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Staff] ([StaffId]),
```

Comment: I believe making the CONSTRAINT StaffId null will give a long term data inconsistency between the table. StaffId seems a primary key in Staff table.